# Performance improvement: Finite Element Mesh graphics

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, finite-element-method

I have created a Finite Elements mesh on GID (quadrilateral 9 nodes elements). I exported the nodes and the elements topology and i'm reading it from the following two text files:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/93b98n139dfep4x/noschapacomfuroleft.txt?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhg8jass0ren6wc/elschapacomfuroleft.txt?dl=0

To read the files above i'm using the following code:

```
    topol = topol = Transpose@Drop[Transpose@Import["C:\\yourfolder\\elschapacomfuroleft.txt", "Table"], 1];
    nnodesx = Import["C:\\yourfolder\\noschapacomfuroleft.txt", "Table"][[;; , 2]];
    nnodesy = Import["C:\\yourfolder\\noschapacomfuroleft.txt", "Table"][[;; , 3]];
    nnodes = ParallelTable[{nnodesx[[i]], nnodesy[[i]]}, {i, 1,Length[nnodesx]}];
```

And then the following code plot's the mesh:

```
allcoords = 
  ParallelTable[
   nnodes[[ topol[[i]][[j]] ]], {i, 1, Length[topol]}, {j, 1, 9}];

allcoords2 = 
  ParallelTable[
   nnodes[[ topol[[i]][[j]] ]], {i, 1, Length[topol]}, {j, 1, 8}];

nodeids = 
  ListPlot[Table[Labeled[nnodes[[i]], i], {i, Length@nnodes}], 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic];

ord = FindCurvePath /@ allcoords2 // Flatten[#, 1] &;

allcoordsNEW = 
  ParallelTable[allcoords2[[i, ord[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length@ord}];

undefplot = 
  ListLinePlot[Tooltip[allcoordsNEW], PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Blue}];

Show[nodeids, undefplot]
```

Which gives:

[image]

The problem is that it takes too long to plot. Is there a way to speedup this code? Is there a beter way to do this? Thank you.

Related paper: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/cae.21958

Comment: Give specific ImageSize to the node plot. The labeling algorithm relies on the information of PlotRange and ImageSize. If you don't specify, the image size will be 300 by default. This can speed things up a little bit, but probably still not satisfactory.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way to speed things up

```
pack = Developer`ToPackedArray;
topol = pack @ Transpose @ Drop[Transpose @
      Import["~/Downloads/elschapacomfuroleft.txt", "Table"], 1];
nnodesAll = Import["~/Downloads/noschapacomfuroleft.txt", "Table"];
nnodes = pack@N[nnodesAll[[All, {2, 3}]]];
```

Now, the idea is to create graphics complexes:

```
(* edges are straight *)
meshVis1 = 
 Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Blue], 
   GraphicsComplex[nnodes, Polygon[topol[[All, {1, 2, 3, 4}]]]]}]
```

[image]

Or, if the edges could be curved, then this approximation is fast:

```
(* approximation to curved edges *)
meshVis2 = 
 Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Blue], 
   GraphicsComplex[nnodes, 
    Polygon[topol[[All, {1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8}]]]]}]
```

The nodes are done separately - this is the slowest part

```
(* this is the slowest part *)
nodeVis = 
 Graphics[{MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #1, {-1, 1}] &, nnodes], {Blue, 
    Point[nnodes]}}]
```

You can combine them with `Show`

```
Show[meshVis1, nodeVis, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]